# flutter doctor warning message

Tags: flutter, android-studio

I am a newcomer who just start learning Flutter. While running the flutter doctor, there's a warning message shown in the Android toolchain, which says that

> Some Android licenses not accepted.  To resolve this, run: flutter doctor --android-licenses

After I run the command, it shows

> 4 of 7 SDK package licenses not accepted. 100% Computing updates...
> Review licenses that have not been accepted (y/N)?

after I choose 'y', it shows some licenses(e.g.

> 1/4: License android-googletv-license:

) and ask for the acception

Should I accept all the other licenses there? Thanks for helping!

Comment: yes. these are safe

Comment: commonly, keep selecting yes until it's done

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have to accept all licenses to develop for Android.